# getting error while connecting sql server using python

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection

I am trying to connect sql server through python and getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

here is my code

```python
import pyodbc
>>> cnxn=pyodbc.connect("Drive={SQL serve}"; server=""; database=""; uid="sa"; pwd="")
```

kindly help me

Comment: You're using semicolons instead of commas, replace all the semicolons you have with commas. `cnxn=pyodbc.connect("Drive={SQL serve}", server="", database="", uid="sa", pwd="")`

Comment: replace semicolon with , even though iam getting same error sir.

Answer (score 1):

The function only needs one argument. So you need to supply the connection string like this:

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SOCKET=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;UID=rooter;PWD=sshh')
```

See https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows for more examples.